# Email rule of the jQuery validation is not working as expected | jQuery Validation | email validation

Tags: jquery, formvalidation-plugin

I am trying to validate my form using jquery validation API and when I set rule email: true then it will say the email address is OK even I have only typed an incomplete email address. This issue also on the official website of the jQuery validation site.

[image]Should I need to add my validation method manually?

Comment: You can Validate an email using HTML if u want

Comment: I think Jq Validation UI is much better than simple HTML validation.

Comment: See[Sets a custom email pattern for the built-in email validation rule.](https://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.methods/)

Comment: Both of them are validating on the front end so they are the same actually using html is better,cleaner, less code to maintain you only have to add only one line

Comment: If jQ form validation API already provide us so Why I need to go with other option.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know this is a good time to give the answer to my own question after a long time. But I achieve the email validation by creating my own rule as below

```
$.validator.addMethod("validate_email", function(value, element) {
    if (/^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/.test(value)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}, function(params, element) {
    return "The "+element.name+" must be a valid email address.";
});
```

and use as follow

```
registerFormEle.validate({
    ignore: [],
    rules: {
        // other rules
        email: {
            required: true,
            validate_email: true,
            maxlength: 255
        }
    },
    messages: {
        // other validation messages
        email: {
            validate_email: "The email must be a valid email address.",
        },
    }
});
```